# How can I insert a string into a string after specific characters?

Tags: php, string

```
$string = 'blue*green-yellow-orange/rosa*white+lila';

$calcSigns = '+-*/';

$addstring = 'color1';
```

Whenever there is a calculation Sign I want to add after the calculation sign the string "color-1".

The result, that I am trying to achieve is:

```
blue*color-1green-color-1yellow-color-1orange/color-1rosa*color-1white+color-1lila
```

This is my approach:

```
$result =  substr_replace($string, $addstring, $calcSigns);
```

But I do not get the correct result.

Comment: Have a look at the second example on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php, it may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`substr_replace()` would make it tricky to preserve the current operation character while replacing. You could instead loop through each character and create a new string out of it.

```
<?php

    $len = strlen( $string );
    $new_string = '';
    for( $i=0; $i<$len; ++$i ) {
        $new_string .= $string[$i];
        if( in_array( $string[$i], ['+','-','*','/'] ) ) {
            $new_string .= $addstring;
        }
    }

    echo $new_string;
?>
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/P5tVr

**Update:**

So, if a operation character is immediately succeeded by a digit and if you want to skip it, and insert `addString` otherwise, it would look something like below:

```
<?php


$string = 'blue+yellow*3-grey+orange';

$calcSigns = '+-*/';

$addstring = 'color1';


$len = strlen($string);
$new_string = '';
for($i=0;$i<$len;++$i){
    $new_string .= $string[$i];
    if(in_array($string[$i],['+','-','*','/'])){
        if($i + 1 < $len && is_numeric($string[$i + 1])) continue;
        $new_string .= $addstring;
    }
}


echo $new_string;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/uQobj

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I have a question, I want to add 'addstring' only if the string is not a number, this means if If have this `$string = 'blue*green*2';` then I like to have the result  `blue*color1green*2`.

Comment: This is my approach:

Comment: `$len = strlen( $string );
    $new_string = '';
    for( $i=0; $i<$len; ++$i ) {
        $new_string .= $string[$i]; if(!is_numeric($string[$i])){
        if( in_array( $string[$i], ['+','-','*','/'] ) ) {
            $new_string .= $addstring;
        }}
    }`

Comment: But the result is `blue*color1green*color12`

Comment: @peace_love Could you explain 'only if string is not a number'? Because only digits or floating point values would be numeric.

Comment: I mean only these ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

Comment: @peace_love So, whenever we come across these digits you want to append 'addString'. Right?

Comment: No, I want to append 'addString' only when after one of these ['+','-','*','/'] not comes one of these ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'] . I am still trying to solve it, but quiet difficult..

Comment: If this is what I have `blue+yellow*3-grey+orange` the result should be `blue+color1yellow*3-color1grey+color1orange`

Comment: @peace_love So if a operation character is immediately succeeded by a digit, you want to skip it. Correct?

Comment: wow how great, I had still difficulties with solving, thank you very much!

Comment: why is it "when string is numeric" then continue. I would assume that if it is "if not numeric" then continue. I just try to understand, why the code is working

Comment: @peace_love Code is same as before, I just added an additional check of whether or not the next character is a digit or not. If the next is `is_numeric()`, then `continue`, meaning, it would skip the rest of the code and go to the next iteration in the for loop, else it would append the `addString`.

Comment: ah, that is why, continue means skip, thank you for your help!